# jena shacl shape max recursion

Tags: recursion, jena, shacl

For a recursive shape, is there a way to limit the amount of recursion in the Jena api of the SHACL Validator?
For example a shape below.

```
@prefix shape: <http://example.org/shape/> .
@prefix person: <http://example.org/shape/Person#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .
@prefix schema: <http://schema.org/> .

shape:Person
    a rdfs:Class, sh:NodeShape ;
    rdfs:label "Person" ;
    rdfs:subClassOf rdfs:Resource ;
    sh:targetClass shape:Person ;
    sh:ignoredProperties ( rdf:type ) ;
    sh:closed true ;    
    sh:property [
          sh:path person:knows ;
          sh:name "knows" ;
          sh:class shape:Person ;
          sh:nodeKind sh:IRI ;
      ] ;
.
```

Is it possible to only validate the "knows" property 1 or 2 deep and let it pass for deeper relations?

Comment: `sh:targetClass shape:Person` so it applies to all instances of `shape:Person`. It is this that causes all the checking. Can you find a way to distinguish instances of `shape:Person` in some way?

Comment: This doesn't look like a recursive shape to me. It would be recursive if you'd replace sh:class shape:Person with sh:node shape:Person. And the sh:targetClass is redundant because you already have shape:Person rdf:type sh:NodeShape (and rdfs:Class).

Comment: Oh you are correct the reason it had recursion because I tried combining all persons in 1, model If I just add a triple to let it know the correct class it works fine without needing to validate all of the shapes.